# JavaScript to check computer for a specific browser

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

In my web site i have this thing it loads a different page if you are in IE 
I loads the no_support.html, and on the no support page i have text saying try one of the two browsers bellow, and bellow i have two images one of google chrome and the other of mozilla firefox, and when you click on any one of them they go to the download page of that browser.

I was wondering is there some trick i can put in the no support page that when for example i open it in IE and this page says try one of the browsers bellow and i click on Google chrome and if i have google chrome installed on my PC it opens my website (supported) with google chrome and if i dont have it then it goes to the download page.

Comment: **use feature detection instead of browsersniffing**, browsersniffing stinks. You might want to take a look at http://modernizr.com/ , it provides a great framework for testing if certain features are available. If these are not available you might want to consider dissabling certain features. (And if it is really necessary, redirect to a "not Sported" page or use an overlay.)

Comment: @gar_onn - True, for websites feature detection is the way to go, but for some websites intended only for certain browsers, and they do exists, like Chrome experiments or Firefox demos, just displaying an icon and a download link will have to do, as you don't have control over the users browsers, at least not enough control to fire one up whenever you feel like it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you can't open a browser on a users computer like that, as that would be a major security issue, and really annoying.

Comment: Agreed, if you can't support IE, links toward Firefox/Chrome/Opera/Whatever websites are more than sufficient.

Comment: yeah, true, that could be annoying and a security issue. Im gona leave it with the links to the download pages.